# Drag and drop and scale images but user's upload pic isn't draggable and resizable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-draggable

Hello guys i found this amazing drag and drop and resize image and i am trying to add a custom modification. I added an upload button so user can upload a photo.

i added the function bellow to find the last img id, create a new one and replace the latest id and img source. The user's photo uploading well but it's not draggable and resizable like other objects.

Official projects link is: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ImageVampUp/

The code that i added is:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$("input").change(function(e) {

    for (var i = 0; i < e.originalEvent.srcElement.files.length; i++) {

        var file = e.originalEvent.srcElement.files[i];

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function() {
        var newoid = parseInt($("#objects .obj_item:last img").attr("ID").split("_")[1], 10) + 1;
        var newoimage = reader.result;  
        $("#objects").append("<div class='obj_item' style='width:80px; height:80px; float:left; margin-left:5px; margin-top:5px;'><img id='"+newoid+"' width='80' height='80' class='ui-widget-content' src='"+newoimage+"' alt='el'/></div>");
        //$('#obj_25').attr('src', reader.result);

        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);        
        }
});

});
</script>
```

and inside projects left bar i added a div with an input so user can load the pic:

```
<input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
```

Comment: After appending the new image, did you try reinstantiating the drag and drop function?

Comment: @ArinCool no i didn't how can do this?

Comment: try the answer i provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just invoke the following putting it in a function after the image is appended:

```
$('#objects img:last').resizable({
   /* only diagonal (south east) */
   handles  : 'se',
   stop : resizestop 
}).parent('.ui-wrapper').draggable({
    revert  : 'invalid'
});
```

Comment: i puted your code after: $("#objects").append("<div class='obj_item' style='width:80px; height:80px; float:left; margin-left:5px; margin-top:5px;'><img id='"+newoid+"' width='80' height='80' class='ui-widget-content' src='"+newoimage+"' alt='el'/></div>"); but it didn't work!! :-(

Comment: @IreneT. Please don't dump code blocks in comments, especially large unformatted blocks. Nobody will actually care enough to read it. Instead, edit your question and update it with the extra information...

Comment: @ArinCool yes i will make a working fiddle and update my post